# React-transition-group Transition doesn't trigger animation on exit

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

My goal is to have an icon spin 90 degrees (become flat) and then to be replaced by another icon, creating a kind of coin-spin effect.

I want then to spin on enter and on exit (there is a delay because of an XHR call).

For some reason, the animation is triggered on enter, but not on exit.

Those are the 3 side types, the `in` state is mutually exclusive.

```
<div className={c.wrapper}>
  <Transition in={loading} timeout={allTransitions}>
    {state => (
      <div style={{ ...defaultStyle, ...transitionStyles[state] }}>
        {(loading) && <SyncIcon className={c.loadingIcon} />}
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
  <Transition in={success} timeout={allTransitions}>
    {state => (
      <div style={{ ...defaultStyle, ...transitionStyles[state] }}>
        {(success) && <SuccessIcon className={c.successIcon} />}
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
  <Transition in={fail} timeout={allTransitions}>
    {state => (
      <div style={{ ...defaultStyle, ...transitionStyles[state] }}>
        {(fail) && <FailIcon className={c.failIcon} />}
      </div>
    )}
  </Transition>
</div>
```

And here are the style definitions:

```js
const duration = 1000
const allTransitions = {
  appear: duration,
  enter: duration,
  exit: duration
}
const easingFunction = 'ease-in-out'

const defaultStyle = {
  transition: `transform ${duration}ms ${easingFunction}`,
  transform: 'rotateY(90deg)',
  alignSelf: 'center'
}

const transitionStyles = {
  entering: { transform: 'rotateY(0deg)' },
  entered: { transform: 'rotateY(0deg)' },
  exiting: { transform: 'rotateY(90deg)' },
  exited: { transform: 'rotateY(90deg)' },
}
```

Here is a demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/coin-state-indicator-3bnv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that `loading` becomes `false` before the exit animation takes effect.

1. You need to remove the conditional rendering.
2. Change the CSS that all transitions "sits" on top of each other

working sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/coin-state-indicator-elutx